# Why are textboxes in usercontrol losing their border when container resized, but only those added via code

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a usercontrol that contains text boxes in a c# WinForms Desktop Application.  I am adding the usercontrols via code to a panel of a splitcontainer:

```
MyUserControl muc = new MyUserControl();
SplitContainer.Panel1.Controls.Add(muc);

//Setting properties of the UserControl here

muc.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top|AnchorStyles.Left;
muc.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
```

When I resize the panels, all the textboxes lose their border.  When I mouse over the textboxes, the borders reappear.

If I do not set the Dock property of the usercontrol, the usercontrol disappears entirely.  Subsequently, when I mouse over the textboxes, they reappear.

Setting no properties of the UserControl above at all has no effect.  Adding the usercontrol to the container after setting all the properties has no effect.

None of the above happens at all when the same usercontrol is added using the IDE.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What tech is this? Windows Forms?

Comment: Question edited to clarify.  It is WinForms.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducable example? When (in an event handler?) are you adding the user control, does the user control override OnPaint() ?

Comment: The UserControl is being added in Form_Load.  No OnPaint() methods are being called.  Didn't think any were necessary.  Not sure how I would provide a code example.  I just created a new UserControl with only a single textbox, and the above behavior is not occurring.  I commented out a considerable amount in my original usercontrol and seeing what happens.

Comment: I figured it out.  I was having Transparency issues earlier in the design of my usercontrol that I was trying to resolve.  After deciding to redesign the usercontrol so I could just ignore the transparency issue, there was code left over that is causing this.  Please see answer below for the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had used the code below that I had gotten from some Googling to resolve a transparency issue I was having.  It resolved the transparency issue, but other issues caused me to do a redesign which made the transparency issue moot.  This leftover code was causing my problems:

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams parms = base.CreateParams;
            parms.ExStyle |= 0x20;
            return parms;
        }
    }
```